# Downgrade to Python 3.5 - python.app conflicts

Tags: python, conflict, downgrade

I am trying to downgrade Python so I can use modules not compatible with 3.6. None of my current modules are non-native as I just clean installed Anaconda.

```
conda install python=3.5.5
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python.app -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> readline==6.2
  - python.app -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> sqlite=3.13
  - python.app -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> tk==8.5.18
  - python=3.5.5
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I don't know how to interpret this. Are there conflicts with Python's native packages?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of install try creating a virtual environment with python 3.5.5 using 
"conda create -n  python=3.5.5" and then try installing the packages you need in the activated environment.

Refer: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands